# Is there a way to check to which mLab account was connected to a heroku app before mLab addon was detached?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab, mongodb-atlas

After mLab addon being discontinued on Heroku, I need to get the database backup from mLab to import it to Atlas. The problem is mLab says that tens of accounts have the email address that was used in Heroku. Is there any way to know which account was used with particular app, so I would get the correct database backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a very good suggestion from Heroku Support.

First examine when was mLab Add-On detached with `heroku releases -a <app-name>`, it should contain the line like

```
v77  Detach MONGODB (@ref:mongolab-xxx)  addons@heroku.com  2020/11/11 05:20:53 +0200
```

Then check the variables used in release before this (in my case v76): `heroku releases:info v76 -a <app-name>`. `MONGODB_URI` should be among the other variables, so it's possible to get correct mLab username from the string and restore the password.